# Can't search for special characters in PhpStorm (Mac problem only)

Tags: utf-8, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to search for specific word in PhpStorm by typing <kbd>Cmd + Shift + F</kbd>, in opened window I'm trying to type e.g. "ķ", "Ō", "ę" or any other of "not standard" letters.

The thing is that as far as in PC version of this program everything is fine, in Mac I can't make it work.
Any idea?

For example "Ń" (alt/option + 1) works fine.

Comment: Please explain "What you can't make work". Are you not able to enter the chars? Does PhpStorm does not find any results but it should? Does PhpStorm showing an error?

Comment: @commonsense I can't type those letters. PS instead does nothing or in specific combination, moves focus on some select etc. So ok, if it actually does something - change focus, or select, then I get it - some shortcuts are set up but if it does nothing, just not showing the letters it should... Then I don't get it.

Comment: What exact keyboard shortcuts are you using to put those chars in, please share two-three examples. Also, what your keyboard layout is at that moment, and what the PhpStorm version is.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov Sorry, I missed your comment. Basically, it doesn't work with every letter that requires "alt". Ō - alt + q, ķ - alt + h, ę - alt + e etc. Ń works but it requires alt and numeric 1, so apparently, there is no problem if using numeric part of the keyboard. My keyboard layout is Polish pro and PhpStorm is 2018.3.3. PS already has some of those combination used for checkboxes in commit panel (cmd+k) because I can see them being unchecked when I write but in search panel nothing is happening so I see no reason why my combinations should not work.

Comment: It must have relation to your specific setup - on my virtual Mojave with 2018.3.3 and the Polish Pro layout, `Alt+Q` inserts `Ō` as expected.
I'd start with renaming `~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2018.3` folder, start with no settings import and check whether it's better now.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov ok, you are right alt+Q works, but alt+A - should return "ą" - does nothing, alt+L should return "ł" - instead checks "Cleanup". My setup isn't specific, I've hanged nothing, it's standard and comes up with installation. Even after renaming preferences I can't type Polish letters in commit window, the only difference is that standard way it's white. My colleague has the same problem, just doesn't care - but it proves that it's not my setup problem.